# Flatten array into single dynamic object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I want to extract object keys into a single array and values in a different array so that I can paste the headers and values into a google sheet.

I want to achieve a dynamic code so that if more fields are pulled in from the API, it can map headers with values.

```
//API Response Sample.
var data =  [

      {
        "actions": [             
          {
            "action_type": "comment",
            "value": "3"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "like",
            "value": "33"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "link_click",
            "value": "1531"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "mobile_app_install",
            "value": "1049"
          }
        ],
        "spend": "8621.03",
        "date_start": "2017-10-28",
        "date_stop": "2017-11-26"
      }
    ]
```

**So far the below code is fixed not dynamic.**

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//flatten the objects
var actionObjects = data.map(returnAction)

//get the headers
var headers = Object.keys(actionObjects[0])

//create a 2D array for rows
var actionRows = actionObjects.map(a => headers.map(h => a[h])) 

//write the headers
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, headers[0].length).setValues([headers]);

//write the rows
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, actionRows.length, actionRows[0].length).setValues(actionRows);
}

function returnAction(data){
  let action = {}
  data.actions.forEach(a => action[a.action_type] = a.value)
  action ['spend'] = data.spend
  action ['date_start'] = data.date_start
  action ['date_stop'] = data.date_stop
  return action
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you want to your question too, please? Note: an object's keys have to be unique.

Comment: Do you mean its 'fixed' because you explicitly access `actions`, `spend` etc? Without knowing the possible shapes your data could take it is hard to offer concrete help.

Comment: @pilchard Here is the end result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6dty.png ( Example from the above API Response) More fields can be added to the API Response such as impressions and CPC. But the overall structure of the response will remain the same.

Comment: Will different objects have varying types of `actions`?

Comment: Within the action object, we can add more action_type with corresponding values. For example, action_type: purchase, and value: 5000. Impressions, CPC, and other fields are added along with spend field, not within the actions object. Users can add more action_type and general fields like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object keys into array:

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
```

Object values into array:

```
const values = Object.values(obj);
```

Or both in one go ...

```
const keys = [];
const values = [];
for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
 keys.push(key);
 values.push(value);
}
```

If the structure of your object does not change... maybe something like this?

```
  const action = {};
  data.forEach(obj => {
    for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        for (const o of value) {
          const a = Object.values(o);
          action[a[0]] = a[1];
        }
      } else action[key] = value;
    }
  })
```

Try this:

```
function setResult() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  class getResults {
    constructor(arr) {
      this.headers = {};
      this.results = [];
      for (const obj of arr) {
        const actions = {};
        for (const [header,value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
          if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            for (const action of value) {
              const values = Object.values(action);
              actions[values[0]] = values[1];
              this.headers[values[0]] = values[0]
            }
          } else {
            actions[header] = value;
            this.headers[header] = header;
          }
        }
        this.results.push(actions);
      }
    }
    get array() {
      const headers = Object.keys(this.headers);
      const results = [headers];
      for (const action of this.results) {
        results.push(headers.map(header => !!action[header] ? action[header] : ''));
      }
      return results;
    }
  }
  const values = new getResults(data).array;
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

This is a whole function which takes in the 'data' array-object and split it out onto your spreadesheet.

Explanation:
This function is mainly written in Object constructor and Classes.

[more about object constructor in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp)

[more about classes in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

According to your sample data, there are Objects inside an Array which I believe that each of those Objects are one set of data.

So, the 1st step is using a `for ... of` loop to work with each data set separately with this line of code `for (const obj of arr) {}`, this is very much the samething as the `var actionObjects = data.map(returnAction)` line in your original code. [more about for ... of in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

With each of your data object, it has 2 main structure,
ONE is `Array: Object: {Key1: Value1, Key2: Value2}`,
which you want Value1 as header and Value2 as the actual value in the output.
TWO is simply `Key: Value` pairs where you need key as the header and value as the value as output.

To work with the given slice of data set, this line `for (const [header,value] of Object.entries(obj)) {}` uses another `for...of` loop together with `Object.entries()` function to deconstruct the given Object into an 2D Array where each of the array value is one Array containing a pair of [key,value] form the given object. [more about Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Afterwards, `if (Array.isArray(value)) {}` will check each value given by the `for...of Object.entries()` function, if it is an Array, it met the condition ONE, else it is condition TWO.

For condition ONE, you want to use the 1st value of the object as header, and the 2nd value as actual value.
`for (const action of value) {}` iterate the 'values' of the object as an array, and store the values as `{value[0]: value[1]}` in the object declared before entering the loop fucntion for later use.

For condition TWO, just store it into the same object as condition ONE uses in the format of `{key: value}`.

At the end of each loop, before going onto the next data object, push the `key: value` pairs stored in this loop (named as `actions`) into result array.

Till this step, you alread have an array which looks like this:

```
Array: [
 Object1: {
  header1: value1,
  header2: value2,
  header3: value3,
  header4: value4,
  ...
 },
 ...
]
```

The Object `this.header {}` is declarated to keep track of the length of max header column counts, and get rip of any duplicates ([since Object keys cannot be duplicated](https://dev.to/marinamosti/removing-duplicates-in-an-array-of-objects-in-js-with-sets-3fep)). This help keep the function working even if some of your data objects may has different headers from the others.

After these loops iterate every object inside your data Array,
custom method created with getter function `get array()` form the final result of all data into a 2D array for the apps script `.setValues()` function to print it onto your spreadsheet. [more about getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

If your main concern is the class and object constructor, here is another version of code without using any of them:

```
function setResult2() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const headers = {};
  const results = [];
  for (const obj of data) {
    const actions = {};
    for (const [header,value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        for (const action of value) {
          const values = Object.values(action);
          actions[values[0]] = values[1];
          headers[values[0]] = values[0]
        }
      } else {
        actions[header] = value;
        headers[header] = header;
      }
    }
    results.push(actions);
  }
  const getArray = (results,headers) => {
    const headers_final = Object.keys(headers);
    const results_final = [headers_final];
    for (const action of results) {
      results_final.push(headers_final.map(header => !!action[header] ? action[header] : ''));
    }
    return results_final;
  }
  const values = getArray(results,headers);
  console.log(values)
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I don't get the desired results. Can you check this - https://jsfiddle.net/analyticonsulting/9yvjbm40/4/

Here is the end result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6dty.png ( Example from the above API Response)

Comment: Try my last function, it totally replaced your whole function, just feed the object constructor with the unmodified 'data' array-object, this should prints out all data to your spreadsheet.

Comment: This code work at my end. Many thanks for writing that. I am just trying to understand the overall structure of the code you wrote. Can you explain a summary on how this is working. Just in pointers for my learning only. I do understand the for of loop but don't really understand the class constructor part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added some explanations and documentation reference.

Comment: Just noticed that you are mainly asking about the classe and object constructor. The classe is only a fancy way of writing object constructor. The getter function is the main reason I choosed to write a class for this script. For short, it is just a way to scipt which makes me feel easier to manage all the data, variables and functions.